# Azure Function Security - Only Allow Logic Apps

Tags: azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I have a logic app that I would like to only be accessible from some specific logic apps that I have.

Is there a way that I can do this with roles or groups?

Answer (score 0):

For this requirements, I don't think we can implement it by roles or groups. According to some test, just found a setting which can set accessible for other logic apps but not specific logic apps.
[image]